# indexOf() showing unexpected value

Tags: javascript

**While doing alert the index of first element i.e, violet is being shown -1.But that is unexpected for getting correct result.Hence i am not able to get the expected result anyone help me so that i can go further in coding.Actually m new to javascript so i am facing such a problem.Hope you will answerme as soon as you can.**

```js
var colors = ["voilet", "indigo", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red"];
var target;
var target_index;
var guess_input;
var finished = false;

function do_game() {
  var random_number = Math.random() * 7;
  var random_number_integer = Math.floor(random_number);
  var target_index = random_number_integer;
  target = colors[target_index];
  alert(target);
  while (!finished) {

    var guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of a color " +
      "violet,indigo,blue,green,yellow,orange,red" +
      "What is the color?");
    alert(colors.indexOf(guess_input));
    finished = check_guess();
  }
}

function check_guess() {

  if (colors.indexof(guess_input) < 0) {
    alert('not present');
    return false;
  }
  if (guess_input > target) {
    alert('you gave large');
    return false;
  }
  if (guess_input < target) {
    alert('you gave small');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` returns `-1` when the element was not found in the array. You have a typo in your `colors` array (voilet instead of violet)

Comment: FYI: The question should not be closed for a simple typographical mistake since that is not the real issue here. Top voted answer of fixing the typo would NOT fix the code.

Comment: The typo FIXED the code.. this was the error

Comment: Incorrect @Weedoze try it... 3 changes are needed to make that code run fully, not one. Your fix will make the alert run, but if you look in the console, there will be an error.

Answer (score 5):

You said that your `guess_input` is `violet` and it returns `-1`

This is the normal behavior because `violet` is not present in your array

```
["voilet","indigo","blue","green","yellow","orange","red"];
```

There is a typo error : you wrote `voilet` instead of `violet`

Answer (score 0):

`guess_input` is defined with a `var` inside of the `do_game` function so it is not global.

You would need to remove the `var` so it can be accessed in the other methods or pass it into the other method.

```js
/* fixed spelling here */
var colors = ["violet", "indigo", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "red"];
var target;
var target_index;
var guess_input;
var finished = false;

function do_game() {
  var random_number = Math.random() * 7;
  var random_number_integer = Math.floor(random_number);
  var target_index = random_number_integer;
  target = colors[target_index];
  alert(target);
  while (!finished) {
    /* removed var here */
    guess_input = prompt("I am thinking of a color " +
      "violet,indigo,blue,green,yellow,orange,red" +
      "What is the color?");
    alert(colors.indexOf(guess_input));
    finished = check_guess();
  }
}

function check_guess() {

  /* fixed typo here */
  if (colors.indexOf(guess_input) < 0) {
    alert('not present');
    return false;
  }
  if (guess_input > target) {
    alert('you gave large');
    return false;
  }
  if (guess_input < target) {
    alert('you gave small');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

do_game()
```

Comment: Incorrect, `guess_input` is `var`'d outside the functions.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol WRONG `var guess_input = prompt ` thanks for the incorrect downvote.

Comment: Huh, redeclared variable. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of violet in your array.

and

```
if (colors.indexof(guess_input) < 0) {
    alert('not present');
    return false;
  }
```

You have a typo here as well. It should be :

```
colors.indexOf(guess_input)
```